# Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive (Chrome Extensions Manifest 3)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to migrate my Chrome extension from Manifest 2 to Manifest 3 but I'm getting the following error

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
> 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-ClANdr6bWuUdXWELI09IBiITbU5zbvg6V1dZp9mr55Q='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

For the code

[image]

I have tried to add

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_page": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-ClANdr6bWuUdXWELI09IBiITbU5zbvg6V1dZp9mr55Q='"
},
```

to Manifest but it didn't help

How can I solve it?

Comment: Extensions can't set textContent or innerHTML of a script element. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) for alternatives.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, I had `elementScript.text = ....`, I replaced it with `Method 1: Inject another file - ManifestV3 compatible` from that answer, put everything in external file instead. Thanks

Comment: @user924 facing similar issue. do you know solution,  could you post as answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access variables and functions defined in page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/access-variables-and-functions-defined-in-page-context-using-a-content-script)

Answer (score -1):

MV3 extensions cannot execute arbitrary stringified scripts, however you can "inject functions" from the background page via the `chrome.scripting.executeScript` API. For example:

```js
chrome.scripting.executeScript(tabId, {
  func: () => {
    alert('hi')
    // The rest of the JS code, not a string
  }
})
```